# Spatial kmeans clustering with additional weight variable

Tags: r, k-means

I have spatial data from visual surveys within which I try to find clusters. Each observation comes with an uncertainty of its true location, which I'd like to include when defining the clusters (i.e. points with better uncertainty have more pull than points with greater uncertainty). I understand that weights are not an option in the base R `kmeans()`, and I couldn't really find anything that's easily enough implemented.

Does anyone know of a solution (package?) that doesn't involve trying to write the entire algorithm from scratch?

```
structure(list(x = c(-5.50944653162014, 0.322787074651102, -2.85296050162562, 
1.82872878969384, -8.85592112139208, -6.2228825532643, 1.44732887460602
), y = c(1.27771601314273, -2.6512125069031, 1.75688441146615, 
-6.54255508859126, 0.774883375306898, -0.46737654252595, -6.33822265443102
), A = c(0.0671140948330034, 0.126207030300347, 0.151890368074839, 
2.20014172575781, 0.39912036345167, 0.341899335816202, 6.30592236975226
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df.kmeans<-kmeans(as.matrix(df[,c('x', 'y')]),3)

ggplot(data=as.data.frame(df.kmeans$centers), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_point(color='red', shape=23, size=3) +
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y,color=A), size=2)
```

[image: kmeans cluster]

In this example, the lighter blue point should have less pull than the two darker ones in that cluster, despite being closer to that one darker point (which should move the centroid more towards that second dark point).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `cclust` from the `flexclust` package. Presumably from your description, the weightings should be the *inverse* of the value of column A, since the light blue dot that you want to have less pull has the highest value.

```r
library(flexclust)

df.kmeans <- cclust(as.matrix(df[,c('x', 'y')]), 3, weights = 1/df$A, 
                    method = "hardcl")

ggplot(as.data.frame(df.kmeans@centers), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(color = 'red', shape = 23, size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(color = A), size = 2)
```

[image]